# How do I overwrite the Gallery.php

Tags: gallery

**How do I overwrite the core Gallery.php?
from**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/block/View/Gallery.php

to

```
**app/design/ ...?**
```

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use a plugin rather than completely overwrite

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/258692/70343

Comment: if I just only modify 1-2 core function, you still suggest to doing by separate plug in.?

Comment: Probably but it really depends what you are doing and the level of change. Plugins have the least amount of impact on the framework and therefore less likey to cause issue if other third party extensions overwrite same functionality. Plus less likely to break with framework upgrades and security patches. But requires more thought on implementation.

Comment: your suggestion is really make sense, however I have no experience to create a separate plug in. need to do some practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can override this file in `app/code` not in `app/design` because you can only override `phtml`, `html`, `xml`, `js` files in `app/design`.

So copy this vendor file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php

here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ImagesConfigFactoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\UrlBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;

class Gallery extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Config\View
     */
    protected $configView;

    /**
     * @var EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $galleryImagesConfig;

    /**
     * @var ImagesConfigFactoryInterface
     */
    private $galleryImagesConfigFactory;

    /**
     * @var UrlBuilder
     */
    private $imageUrlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        array $data = [],
        ImagesConfigFactoryInterface $imagesConfigFactory = null,
        array $galleryImagesConfig = [],
        UrlBuilder $urlBuilder = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $jsonEncoder, $data, $imagesConfigFactory, $galleryImagesConfig, $urlBuilder);
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->galleryImagesConfigFactory = $imagesConfigFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(ImagesConfigFactoryInterface::class);
        $this->galleryImagesConfig = $galleryImagesConfig;
        $this->imageUrlBuilder = $urlBuilder ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(UrlBuilder::class);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection of gallery images
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getGalleryImages()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
        if (!$images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
            return $images;
        }

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $galleryImagesConfig = $this->getGalleryImagesConfig()->getItems();
            foreach ($galleryImagesConfig as $imageConfig) {
                $image->setData(
                    $imageConfig->getData('data_object_key'),
                    $this->imageUrlBuilder->getUrl($image->getFile(), $imageConfig['image_id'])
                );
            }
        }

        return $images;
    }

    /**
     * Return magnifier options
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMagnifier()
    {
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($this->getVar('magnifier'));
    }

    /**
     * Return breakpoints options
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBreakpoints()
    {
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($this->getVar('breakpoints'));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve product images in JSON format
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGalleryImagesJson()
    {
        $imagesItems = [];
        /** @var DataObject $image */
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {
            $imageItem = new DataObject(
                [
                    'thumb' => $image->getData('small_image_url'),
                    'img' => $image->getData('medium_image_url'),
                    'full' => $image->getData('large_image_url'),
                    'caption' => ($image->getLabel() ?: $this->getProduct()->getName()),
                    'position' => $image->getData('position'),
                    'isMain'   => $this->isMainImage($image),
                    'type' => str_replace('external-', '', $image->getMediaType()),
                    'videoUrl' => $image->getVideoUrl(),
                ]
            );
            foreach ($this->getGalleryImagesConfig()->getItems() as $imageConfig) {
                $imageItem->setData(
                    $imageConfig->getData('json_object_key'),
                    $image->getData($imageConfig->getData('data_object_key'))
                );
            }
            $imagesItems[] = $imageItem->toArray();
        }
        if (empty($imagesItems)) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('thumbnail'),
                'img' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'full' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'caption' => '',
                'position' => '0',
                'isMain' => true,
                'type' => 'image',
                'videoUrl' => null,
            ];
        }
        return json_encode($imagesItems);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve gallery url
     *
     * @param null|\Magento\Framework\DataObject $image
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGalleryUrl($image = null)
    {
        $params = ['id' => $this->getProduct()->getId()];
        if ($image) {
            $params['image'] = $image->getValueId();
        }
        return $this->getUrl('catalog/product/gallery', $params);
    }

    /**
     * Is product main image
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $image
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isMainImage($image)
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        return $product->getImage() == $image->getFile();
    }

    /**
     * Returns image attribute
     *
     * @param string $imageId
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @param string $default
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageAttribute($imageId, $attributeName, $default = null)
    {
        $attributes = $this->getConfigView()
                ->getMediaAttributes('Magento_Catalog', Image::MEDIA_TYPE_CONFIG_NODE, $imageId);
        return $attributes[$attributeName] ?? $default;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve config view
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Config\View
     */
    private function getConfigView()
    {
        if (!$this->configView) {
            $this->configView = $this->_viewConfig->getViewConfig();
        }
        return $this->configView;
    }

    /**
     * Returns image gallery config object
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    private function getGalleryImagesConfig()
    {
        if (false === $this->hasData('gallery_images_config')) {
            $galleryImageConfig = $this->galleryImagesConfigFactory->create($this->galleryImagesConfig);
            $this->setData('gallery_images_config', $galleryImageConfig);
        }

        return $this->getData('gallery_images_config');
    }
}
```

You need to add this line in your `di.xml` file in your custom module

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Gallery" />
```

like this..

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Gallery" />
</config>
```

Also you can create plugin and you can use `before`, `after` and `around` actions in that as per **Dominic Xigen's** answer.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use overwrite first, and then if I have spare time, I will spend sometimes to move on by using plugin.

Comment: Can I change app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php to app/code/V1/V2/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php  so the xml I also need to make changes right? like <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" type="V1\V2\Block\Product\View\Gallery" /> .  Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can change whatever functions you want in app/code file

Comment: I am sorry, I just edit my question..  Can I change app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php to app/code/V1/V2/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php so the xml I also need to make changes right? like <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" type="V1\V2\Block\Product\View\Gallery" /> . Thanks

Comment: Yes @PaulFan, Right.

Comment: Do I need to do anything afterward? I try to reindex and cache flush, seems nothing happen.

Comment: @PaulFan, you've created custom module here?

Comment: oh Yes, I create above codes and folders,and place them to the module that already exists at (app/code/Super/).    (app/code/Super/GalleryView/Block/View/Gallery.php ) and  (app/code/Super/GalleryView/etc/di.xml ) I hope I do it right

Comment: After adding di.xml you need to run setup upgrade and di compile command once. then it will work.